# Backtracking namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

Does there exist a way to backtrack a namespace in C++ without using `::fully::qualified::namespace::name` form?

Given:

```
namespace f {
    void p() { }
    namespace g {
        void p() {
           [..]::p();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a correct form of the `[..]`, apart from fully-qualifying it (i.e. `::f::p()`)?
The goal is to *not* use p(), because infinite recursion is not the goal here, while also not using FQ in order to save space.

Comment: `f::p` isn't _fully_ qualifying it. E.g. `namespace f { void p(); { namespace f { void p() { f::p(); } } } }` causes infinite recursion whereas `::f::p()` might not. `f::p` just looks for the nearest `f` and then looks for `p` in whatever `f` it found. In your case `f::p` is the minimum qualification required. You don't need a full `::f::p` although in this case there isn't a lot to be gained.

Comment: ¤ nope, sorry. but it's imho a good idea, and you're not alone in proposing this. as a workaround you can define a namespace alias for the relevant namespace, and achieve the desired usage notation, as [shown here](http://codepad.org/V80j9kbb). cheers & hth.,

Comment: @CharlesBailey Sorry, I meant `::f::p()`. Thanks for spotting my typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name lookup works from inner scopes outwards so you don't need to go from the top down each time. Omitting the leading `::` effectively gives you lookup that backtracks until it finds the name that you are looking for so `f::p` effectively backtracks until it finds an `f` and then looks for a `p` inside that `f`. You don't need a full `::f::p()` although in your case, as `f` is in the global namespace, there isn't a huge typing difference.

Consider this example, where the saving for calling `::f::g::f::p()` is more obvious.

```
namespace f {
    void p();
    namespace g {
        void p();
        namespace f {
            void p();
            namespace h {
                void p()
                {
                    f::p();   // same as ::f::g::f::p()
                    ::f::p(); // fully qualified
                    g::p();   // same as ::f::g::p();
                    p();      // recurse!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no explicit way of forcing lookup to exlcude the immediate scope level (block or namespace, no `..::p()` or `^::p()` or something.